# SSL certificate not working in laravel project aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elb

I am trying to implement SSL certificate on my EC2 instance which is running a laravel project. I have issued the certificate and it is also in use but when I try https://domainName my browser shows

> Unable to connect

I have used:

1. EC2
2. Route53
3. Certificate Manager
4. Load Balancer
5. Elastic Beanstalk

[This](https://infra.engineer/aws/36-aws-ssl-offloading-with-an-application-load-balancer) is exactly how I configured my Load Balancer, Then added my DNS Name to Route53.

I didn't know what details should I provide so please do ask for the information.

Comment: You have to provide more details. How exactly did you deploy the ssl cert on the LB?

Comment: @Marcin [This](https://jianjye.com/articles/22/how-to-setup-aws-elb-with-ssl-for-laravel) is how I created my Load Balancer + I added the DNS Name to Route53

Answer (score 0):

Check the web service if it is working correctly locally in you ec2 and listen on port 8o, then apply ssl offloading with application load balancer:  please check the following example: https://infra.engineer/aws/36-aws-ssl-offloading-with-an-application-load-balancer

Comment: @Arsi Badlah My site is working fine on ``http://domainName``, So according to you I should connect through ``SSH`` to my instance and input all the commands provided in the link that you just shared?

Comment: Good just follow the example I've mentioned to create https listener, configure security groups, etc..

Comment: I've already done that by following [this](https://jianjye.com/articles/22/how-to-setup-aws-elb-with-ssl-for-laravel) tutorial, Still I cannot access ``https://domainName``

Comment: I think your problem in step 9, it mentions how to redirect http to https, but it did not mention https listener creation, it just shows https listenner in the screenshot. could you confirm that you created https listener on port 443?

Comment: I just created a new ``Load Balancer`` by following the steps in link that you provided, I had to use ``alias`` to select my load balancer except this I had followed all the steps as it is and still I don't have the desired results, could it be an instance configuration problem?

Comment: Can you confirm if your ec2 appears healthy on laod balancer target group > Targets?

Comment: @Arsi Badlah I did went to instances and it is healthy and went to targets there it says Port:- 80, Protocol:-HTTP, Target Type:- Instance and Load Balancer:- "MyLoadBalancerName"